# Построение информации о подключениях ssh (linux) с помощью grep

Tags: linux, ssh, grep

Используя команду *grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log*, получаю результат:

> Jan 19 10:09:43 srv_123 sshd[3275]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
>
> Jan 19 12:10:21 srv_123 sshd[3275]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user admin

Что нужно добавить, чтобы получить результат (пользователь | подключился | отключился):

> admin | Jan 19 10:09:43 | Jan 19 12:10:21

Comment: Добавить ... скрипт по разбору этого лога написать. достаточно не тривиальная задача, учитывая, что пользователь мог подключится сегодня, а отключиться через неделю, когда уже того лога в котором было подключение записано в помине нет. боюсь за вас это тут делать никто не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если ограничится одним днем, тоесть днем запуска скрипта (от 00:00 до 23:59). И возможны ли другие способы отображения пользователей использовавших подключение ssh?

Comment: @IgKos А автоматическая запись в *wtmp* / *utmp* чем вас не устроила? Команда `last` (и мануал по ней) всё расскажет. (Очередной из серии *useless use of grep*. Правило здравого смысла, *"Если вы используете `| grep` скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так!"*)

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что простого метода решения этой задачи нет. И Вам не поможет ни использование  grep/awk/sed, ни анализ файлов utmp/wtmp с помощью утилиты last...

Ведь вы хотите получить ПАРЫ Зашёл / вышел. Но далеко не всегда возможно найти такие пары. Ну, про уcтаревание лог-файлов Вам уже писали. Но, есть и другие сложности:

1. Крах системы. Никто из залогиненых не получит запись о логауте.
2. На сервер зашло НЕСКОЛЬКО пользователей под одним логином.
3. . . .

Разумеется, все эти ситуации "разруливаются" некоторыми приёмами. Но никакого ПРОСТОГО способа разобрать подобные коллизии не существует.

Comment: 1. Вы получите запись в журнале об этом событии. 2. Это проблема настройки и администрирования, скорее указывающая на некомпетентность того, кто внедрял. 3. ?

Comment: У меня вот такой вопрос: Вы считаете, что Ваш коммент и вправду поможет TS решить проблему?

Comment: А ваш ответ? Вы, кстати, про который комментарий?